# Overview of common pipe dimension and threads used in espressomachines

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance, troubleshooting, identify-this

Is there a good lookup table for universal espresso parts and common pipe dimensions?

I have been servicing some entry level espresso machines and noticed a lot of similar components (Francis Francis X1, Ascaso Arc, Saeco Starbucks Sin006, Krups 874). As example the first three use an Ulka 5 pump.

However i struggle with determining the dimension of pipe-threads and etc.
As an example i wanted to block the steam outlet with an end cap (they never used it) on a Saeco Starbucks Sin006, but could not identify the thread (~16mm OD and 24tpi).

Also the silicone valve in the boilers (right above shower screen) seems to be identical on X1 and Sin006, but was uncertain if i could just swap.

Is there any source that describe the most common dimensions used for pipes, universal parts and etc.?

So far my best source have been this site on [espresso parts](https://www.espressoparts.com/collections/browse-common-espresso-machine-parts-various-european-bsp-thread-fittings), but still do not feel confident ordering parts unless the model is mentioned.

[image: Picture of steam outlet thread]